# Как правильно пишется слово "вверх"?

Tags: орфография

Вместе или раздельно пишется "вверх" в предложении:

**Перемещая вверх нижние валки, произвести гибку детали.**

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае это наречие( отвечает на вопрос: куда?), поэтому пишется **слитно**. Раздельно пишется сочетание сочетание существительного верх с предлогом (имеет при себе поясняющие слова).

Напр.: **посмотреть в верх горы.**

**На верх платья она нашила множество камней, отчего оно стало выглядеть еще более безвкусным.**

Answer (score -1):

Пишется вместе, так как в этом случае слово "вверх" является наречием.